# how to program a web browser in java blackberry

Tags: text-editor, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, createprocess, geturl

I need to know how to program a web browser in java blackberry;
I don't know how start with this;
maybe can start by put one panel but I don't know what else do.

Comment: ..what do you mean by "program a web browser"? Are you wanting to create your own...?

Comment: if I want to create my own web browser in eclipc black berry with java .... and I need the codes to get started

Comment: This is just Not Going To Happen, sorry. A Web Browser -- even the most trivial -- is far more than a panel :( HTTP communication, HTML parsing, layout & rendering, and then all the "expected" extras (HTML5, CSS, JS)... the device doesn't already have a [WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol) browser?

Comment: as I can get started to program it to me at my university project ....... which is the component which presents the web page ie the web browser screen?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much of HTML/CSS and javascript you want to support, a good starting point is just to do html.

So, you can use kxml (http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/11773) in relaxed mode to parse html, then, as it is parsed you will need to layout the webpage.

I haven't used it in any fashion but the BB webkit components in this bundle may be helpful:
http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/blackberry6/browser_open_source_components.jsp